# LaTex and Spaces

Tags: spacing

Please consider the following block:

```
\begin{align*}
TA2 &= \frac{h}{2} \left( f(1) + 2f(\frac{5}{4}) + 2f(\frac{3}{2}) + 2f(\frac{7}{4}) + f(2) \right)  \\
f(2) &= 8 \\
\end{align*}
```

When it is displayed, there is a small amount of extra white space between the letters T and A. Is there a way to suppress this extra horizontal spacing?

Comment: That is normal: in math mode, TA is considered as the product of the variables T and A. B.t.w., do you want it in italic of upright?

Comment: I think I want the italic. Not sure. I just do not like the space.

Comment: Usually, italic is for maths variables. If you stick to italic, then use `\mathit{TA2}`. For upright letters, its `\mathrm{TA2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have put several options, but the comment of the very good user @Bernard is very important. The "small amount of extra white space" is "normal".

In this MWE I have not seen "small amount of extra white space".

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{TA2} &= \frac{h}{2} \left(f(1) + 2f\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{7}{4}\right) + f(2) \right)  \\
f(2) &= 8 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathit{TA2} &= \frac{h}{2} \left(f(1) + 2f\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{7}{4}\right) + f(2) \right)  \\
f(2) &= 8 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\textup{TA2} &= \frac{h}{2} \left(f(1) + 2f\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{7}{4}\right) + f(2) \right)  \\
f(2) &= 8 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathtt{TA2} &= \frac{h}{2} \left(f(1) + 2f\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{7}{4}\right) + f(2) \right)  \\
f(2) &= 8 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\mathsf{TA2} &= \frac{h}{2} \left(f(1) + 2f\left(\frac{5}{4}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{3}{2}\right) + 2f\left(\frac{7}{4}\right) + f(2) \right)  \\
f(2) &= 8 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like the way it looks the way you did it.